# Regex confusion in python

Tags: python, regex

if i set the variable a to

```
a = "6253625879615786"
```

if i use the regex statement

```
print(re.findall(r'^[456][0-9]{15}[^,_]',a))
```

I do not get any output but if i use the regex statement with the * at the end to 0 or 1 times

```
print(re.findall(r'^[456][0-9]{15}[^,_]*',a))
```

Why is this?

Comment: Your input string is 16 char long. Pattern 1 needs 17 chars to match, while the second one needs 16. `*` means *0 or more occurrences*. Study [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: `*` means "any" number of times, including 0.

Comment: but without the * in pattern one, how does it require 17 chars if I am trying to just omit those the ^, and_ from happening and not actually occur in the string

Comment: the first pattern says it ends with a character that is not , or _ that's a lot of possibilities

Comment: Oh,so with the *, if i have a comma or underscore anywhere in the a variable, it will not print but without the *, regex interprets [^,_] as in the last part of the string should not contain the comma or underscore

Comment: so could i have just used a negative look back like  (?!,|_) instead